# Rails Error: ImageMagick/GraphicsMagick is not installed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, macos, carrierwave, minimagick

I get this error when i ran my rails app on my OSX and i tried to upload an image.

I have a "product" model and i am using Mini_Magick with CarrierWave for uploading the product's image.
When i create a product on my ubuntu's laptop, it works fine, but when i do that on my macbook, it throws the error:

Image Failed to manipulate with MiniMagick, maybe it is not an image? Original Error:

> ImageMagick/GraphicsMagick is not installed

I have done the "bundle install" command and everything works fine... do you know what could be the problem?

Answer (score 50, accepted):

I am thinking that you may now have some of the foundations on your OSX. You can try removing everything and start again:

to uninstall

```
brew uninstall imagemagick graphicsmagick libpng jpeg
brew cleanup -s
```

To install

```
brew install graphicsmagick
```

Hope that this works for you

Comment: in which directory should i run this commands? Because it returns me this error: "Error: No such keg: /usr/local/Cellar/imagemagick"

Comment: How about on windows ?

Comment: @MoussaSarr you may want to check http://www.graphicsmagick.org/INSTALL-windows.html

Comment: It should be capitalized i.e. `GraphicsMagick`

Comment: I will check my sources, and then update the post.  Thanks